# Error while generating build apk file in my android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to build apk file in my android studio but it is generating the following error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd.class

How to get out from this issue and build apk file.

## Mygradle file code is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wedding.weddingapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        configurations { all*.exclude module: 'gson-2.5' }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


repositories {
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/layerhq/releases-android/master/releases/" }
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/layerhq/Atlas-Android/master/releases/" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })

    compile 'com.layer.atlas:layer-atlas:0.3.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: clean your project and then again generate signed apk may this help

Comment: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'`

Comment: use `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`  *25* . Then call `appcompat-v7:25.1.0`

Comment: obviously [com.layer.atlas:layer-atlas:0.3.6](https://github.com/layerhq/Atlas-Android/blob/master/releases/com/layer/atlas/layer-atlas/0.3.6/layer-atlas-0.3.6.pom#L46)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you must be using older version of google services
please make sure `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0` are compatible note don't use `com.google.gms.google-services 9.0.0` please make sure you are using above 9.0.0 version